# Is there an R function to generate a column of U.S county names based on latitude and longitude?

Tags: r, geocode

I have a dataset of ~60,000 observations with a latitude column and longitude column.

Is there a function that can tack on a  "county fipscode" column?

Comment: You may use a web API with R package `httr`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864601/find-county-name-for-a-lat-long.

Comment: Another approach with `sf` and `spData` packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r/8751965#8751965

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko

I'm looking at this answer, which is very related.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316185/r-convert-zipcode-or-lat-long-to-county

However, I'm struggling to see how I would use that on an entire dataframe and make a column name out of the county FIPS codes

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko Oh I think I got it. I had to switch the order the latitude and longitude columns were in!

My only last issue is that now I have a column that gives "state, county"

Would really love to get the county fips code as well

Comment: I would start with `tigris` package, get all the countries with `counties()` function, then find those county which overlaps with point (`st_within` from `sf`). You can build a small function and then mutate it on you data frame like: `CntFIP <- function(point, counties) {
  a <- sf::st_within(point, counties);
  if(length(a[[1]]) == 0L) {
    FIPS = NA;
  } else {
  FIPS <- counties[a[[1]],"COUNTYFP"];
  FIPS <- FIPS$COUNTYFP;
  }
  return(FIPS);
}
`

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko

I'm using the following code


`library(usmap)`

`lapply(split(df, df$state), function(x)`
 `fips(state = x$state[1], county = x$county)) `

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271722/from-state-and-county-names-to-fips-in-r

this prints out the fips of all my counties. But I'm getting errors when I try to turn this into a dataframe column

Comment: @TobinBrooks, open a new question please, putting sample of your data frame if possible.